# How to use nested ternary operator in link_to in rails view?

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, conditional-statements, haml, conditional-operator

I have a Haml line I want to edit to add a condition that if there is only on `not_done_task` as follows:

From this (this line is correct):

```
= link_to "#{not_done_task.count == 0 ? "No" : not_done_task.count} Tasks To Do"
```

To this (this line is not correctly written):

```
= link_to "#{not_done_task.count == 0 ? "No task", not_done_task.count == 1 ? "1 Task", not_done_task.count > 1 ? "not_done_task.count Tasks"} to do"
```

I expect that the `link_to` section recognize three different cases:

```
(if count == 0, if count == 1 ans if count > 1)
```

but my synthax is not correct.

Comment: I'd recommend not using `?:`-based logic and syntax. Instead, keep the code clean and simple and a little more verbose and use regular `if/then/else` in the Haml. In general we disapprove of using `?:` syntax in Ruby because it's not as clear what's happening; The logic of something easily gets lost making it easy for errors and bugs to creep in.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution. However it will make the code hard to read. Ternary operator is better with only two options.

```
<%= link_to (not_done_task.size == 0 ? "No task" : (not_done_task.size == 1 ? "1 task" : not_done_task.size + "tasks to do")) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be something similar to

```
= link_to task_count
```

Where task_count is a (helper) method which contains the logic.

Options below:

1) Syntax for normal if, elsif, else statements:

```
if cond1
  stmt1
elsif cond2
  stmt2
elseif cond3
  stmt3
else
  stmt4
end
```

Syntax for case when statement (my prefered and in my opinion most readable way):

```
case not_done_task.count
when 0
  'No Task'
when 1
  '1 Task'
when > 1
  "#{Not_done_task.count} Tasks"
end
```

Syntax for nested ternary operators (for completeness):

```
cond1 ? stmt1 : (cond2 ? stmt2 : (cond3 ? stmt3 : stmt4)))
```